# How to rewrite DreamBooth loss in terms of $\epsilon$-prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, generative-models, diffusion

I'm trying to make the loss used in [DreamBooth](https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.12242) paper explicit, writing it in terms of the noise, as it is commonly written in the original diffusion article [[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.11239)], instead of the image reconstruction loss that is written in the paper.

The authors use [Imagen](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.11487) text-to-image diffusion model, and the finetuning process is described in the paper as

> A conditional diffusion model $\hat{x}_\theta$ is trained using a squared error loss to denoise a variably-noised image $z_t:= \alpha_tx + \sigma_t \epsilon $ as follows

$$
\mathbb{E}_{x,c,\epsilon,t} \bigl[ w_t \lVert \hat{x}_\theta(\alpha_t x + \sigma_t \epsilon,c) - x \rVert_2^2 \bigr] \tag{1}\label{db_loss}$$

> where $x$ is the ground-truth image, $c$ is a conditioning vector (e.g., obtained from a text prompt), $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\mathbb{I})$
> is a noise term and $\alpha_t,\sigma_t,w_t$ are terms that control the noise schedule and sample quality, and are functions
> of the diffusion process time $t \sim U([0, 1])$

But in the appendix A of the Imagen paper I can see that the model is actually trained on the variational lower bound using the $\epsilon$-parameterization (the model is trained to predict the noise that generated $z_t$ in the forward process)

> We use the $\epsilon$-prediction parameterization, defined as $\hat{x}_\theta(z_t,\lambda_t, c) = (z_t − \sigma_t \epsilon_\theta(z_t, \lambda_t, c))/\alpha_t$, and we impose
> a squared error loss on $\epsilon_\theta$ in $\epsilon$-space with t sampled according to a cosine schedule

The $\epsilon$-prediction parameterization, is described in [Denoising Diffusion Probabilistic Models](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.11239) as
$$\mathbb{E}_{x,\epsilon,c,t} \Bigl[ \frac{\beta_t^2}{2 \sigma_t^2 \alpha_t (1-\overline{\alpha}_t)}\lVert \epsilon - \epsilon_\theta(z_t,t,c) \rVert_2^2 \Bigr]$$

- **Question**: Does the $w_t$ term of equation \eqref{db_loss} refer to the reweighting term $\frac{\beta_t^2}{2 \sigma_t^2 \alpha_t (1-\overline{\alpha}_t)}$? I find this terminology extremely confusing since this is very similar to the *guidance weight* $w$. However, from my undestanding the *guidance weight* is only used during sampling.
- Since the reweighting term was empirically proven to yield better result when set to 1, the loss could be simplified as
  $$\mathbb{E}_{x,\epsilon,c,t} \Bigl[\lVert \epsilon - \epsilon_\theta(z_t,t,c) \rVert_2^2 \Bigr]$$
  I did not find any details about $w_t$ in Imagen paper.

DreamBooth authors observed that training using the loss \eqref{db_loss} led to *overfitting* and *language drift*, so they actually introduced a regularization term in the loss, calling it *Prior-Preservation Loss*

> We propose an autogenous class-specific prior-preserving loss to counter both the
> overfitting and language drift issues. In essence, our method is to supervise the model with its own generated
> samples, in order for it to retain the prior once the few-shot fine-tuning begins. Specifically, we generate data
> $x_{pr} = \hat{x}(z_{t_1}, c_{pr})$ by using the ancestral sampler on the frozen pre-trained diffusion model with random initial
> noise $z_{t_1} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \mathbb{I})$ and conditioning vector $c_{pr} := \Gamma(f(”\text{a [class noun]}”))$. The loss becomes:

$$\mathbb{E}_{x,c,\varepsilon,\varepsilon',t} \bigl[ w_t \lVert \hat{x}_\theta(\alpha_t x + \sigma_t \varepsilon, c) - x \rVert_2^2 + \lambda w_{t'} \lVert \hat{x}_\theta(\alpha_{t'} x_{pr} + \sigma_{t'} \varepsilon', c_{pr}) - x_{pr} \rVert_2^2 \bigr]$$

- Following the previous literature, i would use again the $\epsilon$-parameterization and rewrite the loss as
  $$\mathbb{E}_{x,c,\epsilon,t}\Bigl[ \lVert \epsilon - \varepsilon_\theta(z_t,t,c) \rVert_2^2 + \lambda \lVert \epsilon' - \epsilon_{pr} (z'_{t'},t',c_{pr}) \rVert_2^2 \Bigr]$$

where $\epsilon_{pr}$ is the frozen model predicting the noise of original images,$\epsilon,\epsilon' \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\mathbb{I})$

- **Question**: Do you find this formulation correct?
- Looking into [HuggingFace implementation](https://github.com/huggingface/diffusers/tree/main/examples/dreambooth) of DreamBooth, I find that this formulation is quite coherent with the code

```py
latents =   vae.encode(batch["pixel_values"].to(dtype=weight_dtype)).latent_dist.sample()
latents = latents * 0.18215
# Sample noise that we'll add to the latents
noise = torch.randn_like(latents)
bsz = latents.shape[0]
# Sample a random timestep for each image
timesteps = torch.randint(0, 
noise_scheduler.config.num_train_timesteps, (bsz,),device=latents.device)
timesteps = timesteps.long()

# Add noise to the latents according to the noise magnitude at each timestep
# (this is the forward diffusion process)
noisy_latents = noise_scheduler.add_noise(latents, noise, timesteps)

# Get the text embedding for conditioning
encoder_hidden_states = text_encoder(batch["input_ids"])[0]

# Predict the noise residual
model_pred = unet(noisy_latents, timesteps, encoder_hidden_states).sample
if noise_scheduler.config.prediction_type == "epsilon":
    target = noise
elif noise_scheduler.config.prediction_type == "v_prediction":
    target = noise_scheduler.get_velocity(latents, noise, timesteps)
else:
    raise ValueError(f"Unknown prediction type {noise_scheduler.config.prediction_type}")
if args.with_prior_preservation:
    model_pred, model_pred_prior = torch.chunk(model_pred, 2, dim=0)
    target, target_prior = torch.chunk(target, 2, dim=0)
    # Compute instance loss
    loss = F.mse_loss(model_pred.float(), target.float(), reduction="mean")
    # Compute prior loss
    prior_loss = F.mse_loss(model_pred_prior.float(), target_prior.float(), reduction="mean")
    # Add the prior loss to the instance loss.
    loss = loss + args.prior_loss_weight * prior_loss
else:
    loss = F.mse_loss(model_pred.float(), target.float(), reduction="mean")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this is still relevant, but answering anyway in case someone else is also looking for this.
The formulation looks good to me but looking at the code snipped you copy I think in the loss term it should actually always be $\epsilon_\theta$, since we're interested in the finetuned models prediction of the regularization prompt. So the final formula should become
$$
\mathbb{E}_{x,c,\epsilon,t}\Bigl[ \lVert \epsilon - \varepsilon_\theta(z_t,t,c) \rVert_2^2 + \lambda \lVert \epsilon' - \varepsilon_\theta (z'_{t'},t',c_{pr}) \rVert_2^2 \Bigr]
$$

where for an example where we try to generate dogs, $c$ is the conditioning vector for "a sks dog", $c_{pr}$ for "a dog". Further $z'_{t'}$ is the latent encoding of a sample from the regularization dataset with $t'$ steps of noise added to it. The quote with the "ancestral sampler" refers to the creation of the regularization dataset. So in this case, they generate images using the frozen model directly, which then generates $z'_0$, to which we can add noise and use our finetuned model to predict the regularization class prompt.

Comment: Thanks, I'm wondering what is that in this formulation keeps the generated images near the images generated before finetuning. In theory, I think that this formulation allows the generated images to get better than the ones generated before finetuning (i.e $\varepsilon^{'} - \varepsilon_\theta$
 is smaller than before finetuning), but since the regularization dataset could be small,this could hurt diversity?

Comment: Yes, if the regularization dataset is small, the model could overfit to the new images. That is why it is there in the first place I think (if there was no reg. dataset, then the model would just overfit to the new images). But I think the issue is also there in the original formulation.

Comment: I was thinking that the risk of overfitting could be reduced if the prior preserving term would be $\epsilon_{pr} - \epsilon_\theta$, i.e comparing only the difference in the predicted noise between the prior and the new model for the prior-preserving dataset

Comment: I can imagine something like that would also work (you would still use $z'$ for the prior-preservation, right?). Their formulation basically ensures the performance of the new model "still works" on the regularization dataset. Yours would make sure it stays close to the old model. Can you elaborate how that could result in better performance for small datasets?